# Conventional way to use eloquent on these tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Having the following tables. What would be the best or conventional way to add relationships to these tables with eloquent?

I know that a Many to Many relationship will need a pivot table. The thing I'm not seeing samples of online is how to do a relationship from one table to multiple tables.  In this case being the profiles table to sizes and breeds tables.

```
dogs
  - id
  - name
  - profile_id

profiles
  - id
  - dog_id
  - size_id
  - breed_id

sizes
  - id
  - type

breeds
  - id
  - name
```

In the end I'd like to be able to query something like this:

Dogs that are sizes in(x-small, small, medium) and breeds in(chihuahua, maltese).

I don't want to confuse myself or others by posting what I'm guessing for my eloquent code as I'm not even close.

Comment: I think I wouldn't go with such setup in this case, but here's something for you https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Comment: I didn't quite get exactly what you're trying to represent with your database structure. Could you clarify? If all you want is to be able to perform the described query, why the need for `profiles` at all? Can a `dog` have more than one `size`?

Comment: @Raphael_ a list of multiple dogs can have various sizes. I'd like to know how to setup the relationships with eloquent. Thank you

Comment: I understand you're not specifically asking suggestions about the database structure, it's just that usually when this kind of question arises, it's because there's something odd with it. That's why I ask what your intentions with the current structure are, so that I could probably suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a database structure like below:

```
dogs
  - id
  - name

profiles
  - id
  - size_id
  - breed_id

dog_profile
  - dog_id
  - profile_id

sizes
  - id
  - type

breeds
  - id
  - name
```

Then, create a model for each table and insert [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) such as described in laravel's documentation.
You will need hasMany-belogsTo and belogsToMany-belogsToMany relationships.